# Websocket for .NET Winform

Tags: winforms, websocket

Please provide me with a web socket client for .NET Winforms that is compatible with Web API and `Microsoft.Websockets` package. I have tried with `System.Net.WebSockets`, Websocket-sharp, and they are not working.

Comment: "not working" is not a good problem description. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `System.Net.WebSockets` and WebSocket4Net gives me the error of 404, whereas WebSocket-Sharp gives the error of Invalid Handshake response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found out the cause of the problem. It is that the web socket connection requires two query string parameters.(`ws://localhost/api/ws?username=blah&token=blahblahblah`). If I specify only one parameter or no parameter at all, then the web socket connection throws 404 error. Don't know why.